# How to create SSIS Dynamic Connection

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, connection, bids

I am having 10 different ssis packages.Each and every packages having source and destination connection.
For example taking the data from source and moving to destination .Each and every packages I have created source and destination connection in connection manager.How to create source and destination dynamically instead of creating source and destination each and every packages.
Example shown in the picture below
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "create source and destination dynamically"?  You don't want to drag-drop them onto your dataflow, or what?

Comment: @TabAlleman I mean in the connection manager i have to create source and destination connection dynamically.I want to create single source and destination connection to my entire packages.I don't want to create source and destination connection to my each and every packages.

Comment: You do have to manually create a source and destination connection in every package.  Once it's there, you can dynamically set the connection string, but you do have to manually put a connection manager in the package, to the best of my knowledge.  I've seen people post about dynamically creating SSIS packages, but I've never done it.   Google might have some info about it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Move the connection strings to configuration file. So that you can change whenever you want without editing package. 
To create configuration, in Control flow right click and choose configurations

Or

Goto SSIS menu->Package configurations. Navigate to next step and choose required connections and dynamic variables to config file.

Refer below link

http://www.sqlshack.com/using-xml-file-configure-ssis-package/